# Testing an onclick component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a component A in React
which has an array like this:

```
const mainArray=
[
  {
    "element1": "",
    "element2":[],
    "element3": "",
    "element4": true
  },
  {
    "element1": "",
    "element2":[],
    "element3": "",
    "element4": false
  }
]
```

From component A, mainArray is looped and component B and component C is called based on value of element4

```
state.mainArray
    .map((arrayElement, index) => {
        return arrayElement.element4 ? <ComponentB  
    property1={state.mainArray
    [index].element2} componentAMethod={this.componentAMethod} />
            : <Componentc  property1={state.mainArray
    [index].element2} componentAMethod={this.componentAMethod}/>
    }
    )
```

Component B and C has a react table which renders data from element2 (which is passed as property1) 
There is an onclick button in one of the react table cells in Component B and C, which points to a method in that component childComponentMethod, which subsequently points to componentAMethod

Method in Component B and C:

```
childComponentMethod = (arg1, arg2) => {
    this.props.componentAMethod(arg1,arg2)
}
```

react table cell in B and C

```
<a 

onClick={() =>this.childComponentMethod(arg1,arg2)}> 
</a>
```

Question, is how do i test the onlick functionality of ComponentB and C ?

Answer (score 0):

If ComponentB/C `click` events can be mocked, then mock them using relevant props with `jest.fn()`.
If they cannot be mocked, then you can only `test` their click events if their `click` changes any `state` (by `asserting` the relevant `state`).

In Either cases,

**if** `find('a')` can result in incorrect(*which we are not interested to see*) elements. 
You should give an identifier to the 'cells', (either a special `className` or some `data-*`) to the `a` elements having an `onClick` event.  Lets Say `className="clickableAnchor"`,

then,
 `const wrapper = mountYourComponent();`

then,
`wrapper.find('.clickableAnchor').first().simulate('click')`

then , you can either check the `click` `length` of mocked `jest.fn()` or check the relevant `state` changes.

Does it help ?